# What happens if you choose One City Challenge and No City Razing?

Tags: civilization-5

When setting up a Civ 5 game, can you choose both "One City Challenge" and "No City Razing"?

And, if you do, what are the effects?

Originally asked here:
http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?90964-1-city-challenge&p=1334993#post1334993

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One City Challenge would not be affected by No City Razing. When you take a city in OCC, the city is instantly destroyed. This can even destroy otherwise unrazeable cities such as Capitals and City States.

The only effect No Razing would have would be preventing the AI from razing other AI players' cities.